# asp.net membership provider change of domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

We are in process of moving to a new domain, we are using asp.net membership provider and have near about 1000 plus members and do we need to take care of some issue before moving, or it will work just fine.

as in aspnet_application table it keep a record of current domain, do we need to take care of it.

Hope its not a bad question

Regards
Moksha

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, nothing to worry about moving to a different domain. Membership provider gets its application name from the membership providers section of web.config file. As follows. (Check your web.config file)

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
         applicationName="YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME" 
         ...
   />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

As long as you don't change `YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME` it won't affect.

Hope this helps !